# How to disabled animation on init Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How do I disable animation on page loading?

```
animations: [
  trigger('slide', [
    state('left', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
    state('right', style({ transform: 'translateX(-50%)' })),
    transition('* => *', animate(300))
  ])
]
```

My problem is that the animation is loading on init (going -50% transition and I don't want it onInit. Just click. How to disabled animation to rendering on init. I have logic on click to show or not their div ( animation )

Comment: Could you please show your HTML which uses the animation?

Comment: Yes https://codepen.io/mihaufs/pen/KKpBWyo?editors=1010

Comment: So the state of the animation is bound to variable `isViewable`? How is it initialized in the component?

Comment: As left panel.   @Input() activePane: PaneType = 'left';  type PaneType = 'left' | 'right';

Comment: Try to leave the value `undefined` initially.